# How can I use reflection to determine if an F# union type is an enum-like union (no fields in each case)

Tags: reflection, f#

**Terminology**

For the following post, I will use the term "reference enum" to refer to an F# type that is a discriminated union with no fields in each case. For example:

```
type AReferenceEnum = Yes | No | Maybe
```

---

**Requirements**

I need a function that given a `Type`, returns a `bool` that tells whether the type is a *reference enum* or not.

Given these types:

```
type AReferenceEnum = Yes | No | Maybe

type ARecord = { name : string }

type AUnion = This of int | That of (int * string)

type AEnum = Left = 1 | Right = 2
```

The function would return these values

```
isReferenceEnum typeof<AReferenceEnum> -> true

isReferenceEnum typeof<ARecord> -> false

isReferenceEnum typeof<AUnion> -> false

isReferenceEnum typeof<AEnum> -> false
```

---

**What I've tried**

It seems like the implementation could be done using `FSharpType` and `FSharpValue` in the `FSharp.Reflection` namespace.

I know you can check `FSharpType.IsUnion t` to check if a type is a union, which includes reference enums.

I know you can check `FSharpType.GetUnionCases t` to get a `UnionCaseInfo[]` describing the different cases of the union type.

I know you can check `FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (value, type)` to get the fields of the case that `value` is an instance of, but not other cases.

If I could iterate the fields of each case of the union, then I could check that all cases have 0 fields, and then the type would be a reference enum.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Every time when "we" need something extraordinary from F#, I have a bad feeling that we are missing the essence of the language. Coming from C# / C++ background I've been asking similar questions for quite a while, until I realized that the things can be done _very efficiently_ but _very differently_ in F# in comparison to C# / ... May I ask you why do you need such a functionality from F#? Perhaps, there is a _simpler_ solution, which is completely orthogonal to what you are trying to achieve! The bottom line is that it is fairly likely that you don't need C#-like reflection sorcery in F# :)

Comment: I am trying to generate a TypeScript client for a web service written in F#. The "kind" of type determines the strategy that must be used to translate it to TypeScript.  I am writing this generator in F#.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then, you really *must* look at this: https://websharper.com/ before you go too deep on TypeScript generation route :) . The generation there is as simple as decorating types with `[JavaScript]` attribute. And since TypeScript is a superset to JavaScript it will work out of the box!

Comment: Neat. Just got it working though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This passes your test cases:

```
let isReferenceEnum ty = 
    if FSharpType.IsUnion ty then
        FSharpType.GetUnionCases ty
        |> Array.forall (fun i -> i.GetFields().Length = 0)
    else
        false
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of `UnionCaseInfo.GetFields()`. It was not showing up in intellisense for some reason.