# Another failure at deserializing data with discriminated unions, in F#

Tags: serialization, f#, json.net, deserialization, discriminated-union

Following a question where the answer provided a working solution to serialize / deserialize discriminated unions ([IgnoreMissingMember setting doesn't seem to work with FSharpLu.Json deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364229/ignoremissingmember-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-fsharplu-json-deserializer/62364913#62364913))

I have now a practical case where this fails (although it works in simpler cases).

here is the test code:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

// set up the serialization / deserialization based on answer from:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364229/ignoremissingmember-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-fsharplu-json-deserializer/62364913#62364913

let settings =
    JsonSerializerSettings(
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Converters = [| CompactUnionJsonConverter(true, true) |]
    )

let serialize object =
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, settings)

let deserialize<'a> object =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>(object, settings)


// define the type used
type BookSide =
    | Bid
    | Ask

type BookEntry =
    {
        S : float
        P : float
    }

type BookSideData =
    Dictionary<int, BookEntry>

type BookData =
    {
        Data: Dictionary<BookSide, BookSideData>
    }

    static member empty =
        {
            Data = Dictionary<BookSide, BookSideData>(dict [ (BookSide.Bid, BookSideData()); (BookSide.Ask, BookSideData()) ])
        }

// make some sample data
let bookEntry = { S=3.; P=5. }
let bookData = BookData.empty
bookData.Data.[BookSide.Bid].Add(1, bookEntry)

// serialize. This part works
let s = serialize bookData

// deserialize. This part fails
deserialize<BookData> s
```

the serialized test data will look like this:

> {"Data":{"Bid":{"1":{"S":3.0,"P":5.0}},"Ask":{}}}

but deserializing will crash like this:

> Could not convert string 'Bid' to dictionary key type 'FSI_0023+BookSide'. Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object.

although the serialization / deserialization of the DU through FSharpLu which has a DU converter.

The reason I am trying to find some automated solution, vs writing a custom TypeConverter (besides the fact I've never done it) is that I have a lot of types I do not control to go through.

Here is a fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sx0k4x

Comment: Your `BookSide` is a union which makes it a **complex key** -- one not immediately convertible to a string.  Json.NET doesn't support complex keys for dictionaries out of the box, see [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245/3744182).  If you make `BookSide` be an enum not a union (`type BookSide = | Bid=1 | Ask=2)` then everything seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xBOytT.  If you add `printfn "%s" s` into your own fiddle you will see that the dictionary keys are meaningless `ToString()` values.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not control these types, so I can't move them to an enum; and I've over 30 objects that are all using with DUs to deal with :/ this is why I'm looking for a generic solution

Comment: Then you will need to serialize such dictionaries as arrays, see [Serialize dictionary as array (of key value pairs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12751354/3744182).  Or you could write a `TypeConverter` for your unions, see [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245/3744182).   Do those answer your question sufficiently, or do you need more help?

Comment: Either way the inability to serialize a dictionary with complex keys is a stated limitation of Json.NET, see [It's currently not possible to deserialize dictionaries with complex classes as keys. #516](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/516).

Comment: Also, are your dictionary keys always [enum-like unions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54372056/3744182)?

Comment: If your dictionary keys really are always enum-like unions it might be possible to serialize & deserialize them in compact dictionary format with an appropriate `JsonConverter`.

Comment: @dbc, no, the dictionaries, through the system have a variety of keys (DU, strings and ints). I will look at the links you sent and see if it's possible to serialize the dictionaries into arrays. I have never dealt with custom serializers, etc at all so it's something I need to look into. I will do some reading and report back.

Comment: I think everyone new to F# tries out the two dozen or so Json libraries for F#, either settles on one or gives up.

Comment: @Asti, that’s exactly how it feels right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are using `BookSide` as a dictionary key -- but this is an f# union which makes it a **complex key** -- one not immediately convertible to and from a string.  Unfortunately Json.NET does not support complex dictionary keys out of the box as is stated in its [Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys):

> When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding `ToString()` for the key type or by implementing a [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter). A `TypeConverter` will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.

There are two basic approaches to handling this issue:

1. Implement a `TypeConverter` as is shown in, e.g., *[Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245/3744182)*.
2. Serialize the dictionary as an array of key/value pair objects e.g. as is shown in *[Serialize dictionary as array (of key value pairs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12751354/3744182)*.

Since your data model includes dictionaries with *a variety of keys (DU, strings and ints)* the second solution would appear to be the only possibility.  The following `DictionaryConverter` should have the necessary logic:

```ml
let inline isNull (x:^T when ^T : not struct) = obj.ReferenceEquals (x, null)

type Type with
    member t.BaseTypesAndSelf() =
        t |> Seq.unfold (fun state -> if isNull state then None else Some(state, state.BaseType))
    member t.DictionaryKeyValueTypes() = 
        t.BaseTypesAndSelf()
            |> Seq.filter (fun i -> i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Dictionary<_,_>>)
            |> Seq.map (fun i -> i.GetGenericArguments())

type JsonReader with
    member r.ReadAndAssert() = 
        if not (r.Read()) then raise (JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream."))
        r
    member r.MoveToContentAndAssert() =
        if r.TokenType = JsonToken.None then r.ReadAndAssert() |> ignore
        while r.TokenType = JsonToken.Comment do r.ReadAndAssert() |> ignore
        r

type internal DictionaryReadOnlySurrogate<'TKey, 'TValue>(i : IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue>) =
    interface IReadOnlyDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> with
        member this.ContainsKey(key) = i.ContainsKey(key)
        member this.TryGetValue(key, value) = i.TryGetValue(key, &value)
        member this.Item with get(index) = i.[index]
        member this.Keys = i.Keys :> IEnumerable<'TKey>
        member this.Values = i.Values :> IEnumerable<'TValue>
        member this.Count = i.Count
        member this.GetEnumerator() = i.GetEnumerator()
        member this.GetEnumerator() = i.GetEnumerator() :> IEnumerator        

type DictionaryConverter () =
    // ReadJson adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633769/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451990/newtonsoft-json-deserialize-dictionary-as-key-value-list-from-datacontractjsonse
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc
    inherit JsonConverter()

    override this.CanConvert(t) = (t.DictionaryKeyValueTypes().Count() = 1) // If ever implemented for IReadOnlyDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> then reject DictionaryReadOnlySurrogate<'TKey, 'TValue>

    member private this.ReadJsonGeneric<'TKey, 'TValue> (reader : JsonReader, t : Type, existingValue : obj, serializer : JsonSerializer) : obj =
        let contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(t)
        let dict = if (existingValue :? IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue>) then existingValue :?> IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> else contract.DefaultCreator.Invoke() :?> IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue>
        match reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType with 
        | JsonToken.StartArray -> 
            let l = serializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<'TKey, 'TValue>>>(reader)
            for p in l do dict.Add(p) 
            dict :> obj
        | JsonToken.StartObject ->
            serializer.Populate(reader, dict)
            dict :> obj
        | JsonToken.Null -> null // Or throw an exception if you prefer
        | _ -> raise (JsonSerializationException(String.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType)))

    override this.ReadJson(reader, t, existingValue, serializer) = 
        let keyValueTypes = t.DictionaryKeyValueTypes().Single(); // Throws an exception if not exactly one.
        let m = typeof<DictionaryConverter>.GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public);
        m.MakeGenericMethod(keyValueTypes).Invoke(this, [| reader; t; existingValue; serializer |])

    member private this.WriteJsonGeneric<'TKey, 'TValue> (writer : JsonWriter, value : obj, serializer : JsonSerializer) =
        let dict = value :?> IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue>
        let keyContract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof<'Key>)
        // Wrap the value in an enumerator or read-only surrogate to prevent infinite recursion.
        match keyContract with
        | :? JsonPrimitiveContract -> serializer.Serialize(writer, new DictionaryReadOnlySurrogate<'TKey, 'TValue>(dict)) 
        | _ -> serializer.Serialize(writer, seq { yield! dict }) 
        ()

    override this.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) = 
        let keyValueTypes = value.GetType().DictionaryKeyValueTypes().Single(); // Throws an exception if not exactly one.
        let m = typeof<DictionaryConverter>.GetMethod("WriteJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public);
        m.MakeGenericMethod(keyValueTypes).Invoke(this, [| writer; value; serializer |])
        ()
```

Which you would add to settings as follows:

```ml
let settings =
    JsonSerializerSettings(
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Converters = [| CompactUnionJsonConverter(true, true); DictionaryConverter() |]
    )
```

And generates the following JSON for your `bookData`:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Key": "Bid",
      "Value": [
        {
          "Key": 1,
          "Value": {
            "S": 3.0,
            "P": 5.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Ask",
      "Value": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Notes:

- The converter works for all `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` types (and subtypes).
- The converter detects whether the dictionary keys will be serialized using a primitive contract, and if so, serializes the dictionary compactly as a JSON object.  If not the dictionary is serialized as an array.  You can observe this in the JSON shown above: the `Dictionary<BookSide, BookSideData>` dictionary is serialized as a JSON array, and the `Dictionary<int, BookEntry>` dictionary is serialized as a JSON object.

  During deserialization the converter detects whether the incoming JSON value is an array or object, and adapts as required.
- The converter is only implemented for the mutable .Net `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type.  The logic would require some slight modification to deserialize the immutable [`Map<'Key,'Value>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5b%27key%2c%27value%5d-class-%5bfsharp%5d) type.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X8zxmI).

Comment: very good; thanks; let me give that a test and I'll report here!

Comment: @Thomas - what was the result?

Comment: I’m in the middle of a move :) should be back at the computer in a few days